# Call a controller action from view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to call an action from the controller using `onclick` method. For some reason it's not returning action I want, it's always jumping to `public ActionResult Index()` by default.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("RegisterIndex", "Register")'"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**NOTE**

I have created view automatically with a model. It's validating input for me by using already generated javascripts. If I change input tag to button it's not gonna do the required validation.

Comment: Do you have this inside a form?

Comment: @Moe Yes it is inside a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.location.href` does a `GET` request, that's why it didn't pass your input values to the server.

When you have `<input type="submit">` inside a form, clicking it will submit the form with all data you need. I think this is what you want, but you just want it to submit to another `action`.

To achieve this, I suggest this solution:

1. Create a `hidden` field in the form. Its data will be sent to the server.
2. In your server, base on that `hidden` value, you can `redirect` to the appropriate `action`

Please feel free to ask me if you find anything unclear :)

Answer (score 1):

The `<input type="submit">`, when inside a form element, will submit the form when clicked unless you return false or `event.preventDefault();`

returning false will prevent the default behavior for your submit.

**EDIT**

`window.location.href` will cause a GET request so your data will not be posted using this method.

**HTML**

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit"  id="btnSubmit" value="Register" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </div>
    </div>
  }
```

**Javascript**

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () { window.location.href = '@Url.Action("RegisterIndex", "Register")'; return false; });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Now it is calling the ActionResult i want, but it is not validating input and also it's not passing input values just null.

Comment: You will need to return false when using a submit. Answer has been updated

Comment: Would you tell me what is 'Home/About'?

Comment: That was just a test. Updated

Comment: As AnhTriet stated, this is a get so your data will not be posted. Follow his great suggestion.